# Function scope tracing possible in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, scope, trace

I'm currently working on a logging interface for a JavaScript (which I'm not into yet) application and I wonder if it's possible to do track a function scope in JS.

In C++ I could do sth. like

```
int some_function(int arg1) {
    function_tracer(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    do_something();
}
```

which works with the [RAII idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization), and in Python I would use decorators:

```
@function_tracer
def some_function(arg1)
    do_something()
```

Both approaches are function scope aware (at least somewhat) with the following benefits over a `enter_scope()` / `leave_scope()` approach like described:

- I don't have to write a `leave()`-Call at all
- multiple `return` statements don't require multiple `leave()` calls
- most important: it's exception safe!

How do I do this in JavaScript? Examples I found put the functions to trace as arguments to a wrapper function (like with decorators in Python).

Is this the only way to do this in JavaScript?

What are your approaches?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? If it is to access the stack of a Function call, on most browsers there is an non-standard `.stack` property on Error objects, so you can do `new Error('trace').stack` to access it as a string, with no standardized format though...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can see the `Call Stack` `Scope` on the RHS when you open the debugger and then choose the `Sources` tab in the console. Make sure you have a debug point set on a particular line of code to know its call stack and scope.